# UITabBar overlaps with content view. How can I access the content view to update its frame?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I've implemented a UITabBar that changes its height depending on a property the UITabBarController is observing.

When the tab bar should increase in height, I make a call to `sizeToFit` and then `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded`. Within `willLayoutSubviews`, I change the frame height of the content view, which I believe to be `self.selectedViewController.view`, however, the change doesn't stick and at some point that view gets set back to the height of the screen. The end result is that the content view extends past the tab bar, with the tab bar overlapping the content.

However, when I switch tabs/view controllers, the content view resizes correctly. How can I correct this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is you are calling the layoutIfNeeded to refresh the UI in

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
}
```

and not in this method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion although I think you might have conflated the two ideas. I am not calling `layoutIfNeeded` in the delegate methods. I am calling it elsewhere where I am observing a change in some other property. Calling layoutIfNeeded, with a custom `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method is not correctly resizing the content view, however, selecting another tab item and going through `tabBarController:didSelectViewController` is correctly resizing the content view